# Query to fetch MsSQL table unique index and primary keys

Tags: sql-server, indexing

```
SELECT sysobjects.xtype, syscolumns.name, sysindexkeys.indid, sysobjects.type
FROM
    syscolumns
LEFT JOIN sysobjects ON syscolumns.id = sysobjects.id
LEFT JOIN sysindexkeys ON (
     syscolumns.id = sysindexkeys.id AND syscolumns.colid = sysindexkeys.colid
)
WHERE sysobjects.name = '{$table}'
AND sysindexkeys.indid IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY sysindexkeys.indid, sysindexkeys.keyno
```

I'm actually using the following query in order to retreive the column name and the keyno.

The problem is my table has 3 fields:

```
user_id
config_name
config_value
```

With a primary key on user_id AND config_name.

I would expect to get the collection:

```
[
  ['name' => 'user_id', 'keyno' => 1],
  ['name' => 'config_name', 'keyno' => 1]
]
```

But i get :

```
[
  ['name' => 'user_id', 'keyno' => 1],
  ['name' => 'config_name', 'keyno' => 2]
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

**edit:** 
I get the same weirdos results using a two index table

table:
    project_image_id
    project_id
    project_image_src

PK on project_image_id AND unique index on project_id AND project_image_src

Expected:

```
[
  ['name' => 'project_image_id', 'keyno' => 1],
  ['name' => 'project_id', 'keyno' => 2]
  ['name' => 'project_image_src', 'keyno' => 2]
]
```

But i get :

```
[
  ['name' => 'project_image_id', 'keyno' => 1],
  ['name' => 'project_id', 'keyno' => 1]
  ['name' => 'project_image_src', 'keyno' => 2]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems correct to me, your index has 2 columns, user_id has position 1 and config_name has position 2

From BOL keyno: Position of the column in the index

why do you think they would both be 1?

Here you go, you needed to join back to the sysobject table but on the index not the table itself

```
SELECT s2.xtype, syscolumns.name, sysindexkeys.indid, sysobjects.type
FROM
    syscolumns
LEFT JOIN sysobjects ON syscolumns.id = sysobjects.id
LEFT JOIN sysindexkeys ON (
     syscolumns.id = sysindexkeys.id AND syscolumns.colid = sysindexkeys.colid
)
join sysobjects s2 on s2.parent_obj = sysindexkeys.id
WHERE sysobjects.name = '{$table}'
and s2.type = 'K'
AND sysindexkeys.indid IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY sysindexkeys.indid, sysindexkeys.keyno
```

Comment: Ok so the indexid is indid ?
How can i determine whether the key is a primary or unique index not a simple index?

Comment: look at xtype in sysobjects
PK = PRIMARY KEY constraint (type is K)
UQ = UNIQUE constraint (type is K)

Comment: Right, both my sysobjects.type and sysobjects.xtype are 'U'

Comment: I updated my query (at the top), and i get both type and xtype = 'U'. On the doc you sent me i read U means table? What does that mean?

Comment: One litte question left :) How do i know if this key is unique?

Comment: Primary key is always unique so is a unique constraint, the difference is that a table can only have 1 PK and many unique constraints and a unique constraint allows one NULL while a PK does not allows any nulls at all

Comment: I'm aware of that, but even if i set an index with 'Unique' to false i retreive it in my query. I would like to know to reject no unique indexes.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple decent Primary Key solutions, but they do not completely answer the request.  It was also asked how to determine if a column is a Unique Index.

**Option 1:**

To determine a unique index, the following system function works to tell you the status of a specific index, "IndexName," in table "TableName":

```
SELECT INDEXPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('TableName'),'IndexName','IsUnique')
```

**Option 2:**

However, the question above stems from a desire to know if a COLUMN is a unique index.  This means that you need a list of all indexes for which the column in question is the only column in the index.  Therefore, a combination like this can be used:

```
-- Note: If a "1" appears in the select below, the index (and by extension, the column) is a unique index.


SELECT si.name, INDEXPROPERTY(x.TableID,si.name,'IsUnique') [IsUnique]
FROM sysindexes si
JOIN (SELECT OBJECT_ID('TableName') [TableID]) x  -- HERE IS YOUR TABLE NAME
  ON si.id = x.TableID
-- This restricts the selection to your column.
JOIN (
    SELECT id, indid 
    FROM sysindexkeys
    WHERE colid IN (
        -- For 2005 and up: SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('TableName'), 'ColumnName', 'ColumnId')
        SELECT colid
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE name IN ('ColumnName')              -- HERE IS YOUR COLUMN NAME
    )
) y
  ON si.indid = y.indid
 AND x.TableID = y.id
WHERE si.status <> 0
  -- This eliminates occurrences of the column found in indexes with multiple columns.
  AND si.indid NOT IN (
    SELECT indid
    FROM sysindexkeys
    WHERE id = x.TableID
    GROUP BY indid
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

**Option 3:**

Create a table (IndexTable) with index_name, index_description, index_keys, and insert the results from the following command:

```
sp_helpindex 'TableName'
```

Then, query from this result (or use a similar query):

```
SELECT *
FROM IndexTable
WHERE index_description LIKE '%unique%'
  AND index_keys = 'ColumnName'
```

Hope this helps, or please post if you have a more concise solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT A.TABLE_NAME, A.CONSTRAINT_NAME, B.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS A, 
         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE B
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND
          A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = B.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
          A.TABLE_NAME='{$tableName}'
    ORDER BY A.TABLE_NAME
```

Replace `{$tableName}` with your table name and you will get all of the primary keys for a particular table, regardless of whether the table has a single primary key or multiple primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sc.name 
  from sys.indexes si 
          join sys.tables st 
             on si.object_id = st.object_id
          join sys.index_columns sic 
             on sic.object_id = si.object_id and 
                sic.index_id = si.index_id
          join sys.columns sc 
             on sic.object_id = sc.object_id and 
                sic.column_id = sc.column_id
  where st.name = @table_name and 
        si.is_primary_key = 1
  order by sic.index_column_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get the "Position of the column in the index". In that way, it does not exists two columns with the same position.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now is there a way to determine wether or not a column is a unique index?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sysobjects.name , syscolumns.name, systypes.name, syscolumns.length ,
       syscolumns.xprec , syscolumns.xscale ,

( 
SELECT 'PK'
  FROM syscolumns C
 WHERE C.name = syscolumns.name AND C.id IN (SELECT O.id
                  FROM sysobjects O
                 WHERE O.name = sysobjects.name)
   AND C.colid IN (SELECT SIK.colid 
                   FROM sysindexkeys SIK 
                   JOIN sysobjects SO ON SIK.id= SO.id  
                  WHERE SIK.indid = 1
                    AND SO.[name] = sysobjects.name)
)
FROM 
    sysobjects , syscolumns 
       , systypes  
    WHERE 
    sysobjects.xtype='U' 
    AND sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id AND syscolumns.xtype=systypes.xtype
    AND sysobjects.name LIKE ?
 ORDER BY sysobjects.name  , syscolumns.COLORDER
```