# Getting all table keys with types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I've managed to cobble together this query from various examples to get all table keys:

```
select tbl.name,idx.name as indexname,t1.*,col.name as colname
from dbo.sysindexkeys as t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysindexes as idx on (t1.id=idx.id and t1.indid=idx.indid)
LEFT JOIN dbo.syscolumns as col on (col.id=t1.id and col.colid=t1.colid)
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysobjects as tbl on (idx.id=tbl.id)
ORDER BY tbl.name,idx.name,t1.keyno
```

The only other thing I need is the type of the keys, which as I understand should be `PK`,`UQ`, or `D` (not concerned with foreign keys at the moment). It appears I need to join `sysobjects` again to get the `xtype` column, but I can't figure out the correct way to do the join.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578418/query-to-fetch-mssql-table-unique-index-and-primary-keys/578470#578470) I tried

```
select tbl.name,idx.name as indexname,s2.xtype,t1.*,col.name as colname
from dbo.sysindexkeys as t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysindexes as idx on (t1.id=idx.id and t1.indid=idx.indid)
JOIN sysobjects s2 on s2.parent_obj = t1.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.syscolumns as col on (col.id=t1.id and col.colid=t1.colid)
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysobjects as tbl on (idx.id=tbl.id)
ORDER BY tbl.name,idx.name,t1.keyno
```

but this results in multiple records per index column and with different xtypes. I want one row per index column (if index is on three columns, then there should be three rows) all with the correct xtype. What do I need to change?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? All these views are deprecated.

Comment: `select @@Version`: Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.760 (Intel X86)   Dec 17 2002 14:22:05   Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation  Desktop Engine on Windows NT 5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 2)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `status` of `sysindexes` to determine the key type. The query could be about the following

```
SELECT c.name AS [schema], a.name AS table_name, b.name AS key_name,
    CAST(CASE WHEN b.status&2048<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS is_PK_constraint,
    CAST(CASE WHEN b.status&4096<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS is_UNIQUE_constraint,
    CAST(CASE WHEN b.status&16<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS is_clustered,
    CAST(CASE WHEN b.status&2<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS is_unique_index,
    CAST(CASE WHEN b.status&64<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS is_allows_duplicate
FROM sysobjects a 
    INNER JOIN sysindexes b ON a.id = b.id 
    INNER JOIN sysusers c ON a.uid = c.uid 
WHERE b.status&0x800000=0 AND c.name<>'sys'
ORDER BY c.name, a.name, b.name
```

I hope this will work in the retro version of SQL Server (SQL Server 2000) which you currently use.

Answer (score 1):

I went into your original sql statement and got it to return the `xtype` for the index from the `sysobjects` table:

```
select tbl.name,idx.name as indexname,t1.*,col.name as colname, tbl2.xtype
from dbo.sysindexkeys as t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysindexes as idx on (t1.id=idx.id and t1.indid=idx.indid)
LEFT JOIN dbo.syscolumns as col on (col.id=t1.id and col.colid=t1.colid)
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysobjects as tbl on (idx.id=tbl.id)
JOIN dbo.sysobjects AS tbl2 ON (idx.id = tbl2.parent_obj) AND (idx.name = tbl2.name)
ORDER BY tbl.name,idx.name,t1.keyno
```

The `idx.id` is the id of the table the index is related to.  There is nothing in the `sysobjects` table except the name field that matches what is in the `sysindexes` table so had to join on that too.  Almost did another left join but when I did, I got rows from the index table for statistic objects that are not listed in the `sysobjects` table.

EDIT:
I went back and looked at what it would take to get the information you are looking for and came up with the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT name, indexname, id, indid, colid, keyno, colname, 
    ISNULL(xtype, CASE WHEN is_index = 1 THEN 'IX' WHEN status&2 <> 0 THEN 'UQ' ELSE xtype END) as xtype
FROM 
(select TOP 100 PERCENT
    tbl.name,
    idx.name as indexname,
    t1.*,
    col.name as colname, 
    idx.status, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN (idx.status=0 OR idx.status&5<>0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS is_index,
    CAST(CASE WHEN idx.status&64<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS is_statistic,
    tbl2.xtype
from dbo.sysindexkeys as t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysindexes as idx on (t1.id=idx.id and t1.indid=idx.indid)
LEFT JOIN dbo.syscolumns as col on (col.id=t1.id and col.colid=t1.colid)
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysobjects as tbl on (idx.id=tbl.id)
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysobjects AS tbl2 ON (idx.id = tbl2.parent_obj) AND (idx.name = tbl2.name)
ORDER BY tbl.name,idx.name,t1.keyno) AS dts
WHERE is_statistic = 0
```

I am not sure how to get the `'D'` types to show as they are not in the `sysindexkeys` table either.

Comment: This appears to only return the primary keys when I run it. I don't have enough experience with MS SQL to even guess why.

Comment: After looking some more.  It looks like normal indexes are not in the sysobjects table in Sql Server 2000.  Because of that the join is leaving them out.  Not sure how to modify it to show indexes without showing statistics.  If you change the last JOIN to a LEFT JOIN then you will get the items that are in the sysindexes table even if they are not in the sysobjects table.